# How to count the number of items in a txt file?

Tags: python

I have a bunch of different numbers all spread out in a .txt file, I am trying to find the number of numbers in the file using python. How would I do it?

[image: File]

Comment: is this txt csv ?

Comment: That's not a text file. Is it a CSV file? Please post a sample of the text file itself.

Comment: By "count the number of items" are you summing the values in the file or would both 1 and 88 count as one apiece?

Comment: Not it is not a csv file it is an excel but I have to open it as a txt file so the program I am using recognizes it. I am trying to find the number of numbers in a file one a piece.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to just read the entire text file into a string, then use `re.findall` to count the number of numbers:

```py
import re

with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

number_count = len(re.findall(r'\d+', data))
print(number_count)
```